# applying color with jQuery to a td element in php for-loop not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a php for loop And I am trying to make all the td elements with class c yellow if the value of that particular element is less then 3. But for some reason it's not working

```
<?php
foreach($results as $data){

  echo '<tbody>
      <tr class="dropDown">
      <td>1</td>
      <td>'.$data['Title'].'</td>
      <td class="c" >'.$data['criticality'].'</td>
      <td class="p">'.$data['Priority'].'</td>
      <td>'.$data['Description'].'</td>
      <td>'.$data['Date_Submitted'].'</td>
      <td>'.$data['no'].'</td>
  </tr>

  </tbody>';}
```

I am using jQuery to achieve this.

My jQuery Code:

```
if (parseInt($(".c").text()) <= 3)
{
    $(".c").css("background-color" , "yellow");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to loop:

```
$(".c").each(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass("yellow",+$(this).text() <= 3);
});
```

Or if you only have 3 values:

```
$(".c:contains(3), .c:contains(2), .c:contains(1)").addClass("yellow")
```

or on the server

```
<td class="c'.($data['criticality']<=3?" yellow":"").' >'.$data['criticality'].'</td>
```

I suggest you move the tbody outside the loop

```js
$(".c").each(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass("yellow", +$(this).text() <= 3);
});
```

```css
.yellow {
  background-color: yellow
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="dropDown">
      <td>1</td>
      <td>'.$data['Title'].'</td>
      <td class="c">4</td>
      <td class="p">'.$data['Priority'].'</td>
      <td>'.$data['Description'].'</td>
      <td>'.$data['Date_Submitted'].'</td>
      <td>'.$data['no'].'</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="dropDown">
      <td>1</td>
      <td>'.$data['Title'].'</td>
      <td class="c">3</td>
      <td class="p">'.$data['Priority'].'</td>
      <td>'.$data['Description'].'</td>
      <td>'.$data['Date_Submitted'].'</td>
      <td>'.$data['no'].'</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="dropDown">
      <td>1</td>
      <td>'.$data['Title'].'</td>
      <td class="c">5</td>
      <td class="p">'.$data['Priority'].'</td>
      <td>'.$data['Description'].'</td>
      <td>'.$data['Date_Submitted'].'</td>
      <td>'.$data['no'].'</td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

:contains:

```js
$(".c:contains(3), .c:contains(2), .c:contains(1)").addClass("yellow")
```

```css
.yellow {
  background-color: yellow
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="dropDown">
      <td>1</td>
      <td>'.$data['Title'].'</td>
      <td class="c">2</td>
      <td class="p">'.$data['Priority'].'</td>
      <td>'.$data['Description'].'</td>
      <td>'.$data['Date_Submitted'].'</td>
      <td>'.$data['no'].'</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="dropDown">
      <td>1</td>
      <td>'.$data['Title'].'</td>
      <td class="c">3</td>
      <td class="p">'.$data['Priority'].'</td>
      <td>'.$data['Description'].'</td>
      <td>'.$data['Date_Submitted'].'</td>
      <td>'.$data['no'].'</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="dropDown">
      <td>1</td>
      <td>'.$data['Title'].'</td>
      <td class="c">5</td>
      <td class="p">'.$data['Priority'].'</td>
      <td>'.$data['Description'].'</td>
      <td>'.$data['Date_Submitted'].'</td>
      <td>'.$data['no'].'</td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thankyou for replying me back. The problem is not even a single td is getting a background color.

Comment: One Word : - Guinness

Comment: See new update - if there are only 1,2,3 you can use one statement without looping yourself

Comment: PS: I'll take a lager shandy :)

Answer (score 1):

You are using the `Class Selector` which returns a `Collection` of HTML Elements.

```js
$(".c").each(function() {
 $(this).css("background-color" , "yellow");
 })
```

```css
.c {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="c"></div>
<hr>
<div class="c"></div>
```

Comment: Where is the test for value? Your code can be written `$(".c").css("background-color" , "yellow");`